# submitted two answer but stackoverflow recognize as two different login

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

I submitted two answer with the same email address and name, but stackoverflow recognize them as two different login. These are my answers:

[Qt - QTableView and QSqlQueryModel items disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818322/qt-qtableview-and-qsqlquerymodel-items-disappear/12824830#12824830)

[Qt: Drop-down button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695313/qt-drop-down-button/12815313#12815313)

thanks all for help.

Comment: You need to register one of your accounts (set an OpenID) and then follow the instructions at [this FAQ entry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/131713). You've already done the first part. Your registered account (which is associated with this Meta SO account) is [1735667](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1735667/alberto) and your unregistered account is [1734193](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1734193/alberto).